# How to use Application Insights to find failure dependences

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

A recent release of our application generated many 400/500 HTTP Failures in Application Insights. Some of these failures failed because they are dependent on a previous API that failed.

[image]

In the image below we can see failed dependencies, but when I drill into them I cannot for the life of me find what API they are dependent on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nav to azure portal -> application insights -> Logs, then write query(note: select a proper "Time range" before run the query) like

```
dependencies 
| where success == "False"
```

the details looks like the screenshot below:

[image]

and also, you can try click on the "Application map" menu on the left pane of your application insights.

Comment: Ivan this is very good, I was able to create a query that works for what I need and I see results when I run it.

Comment: Ivan this is very good, I was able to create a query that works for what I need and I see results when I run it.

However when I save the query I can no longer find it. I saved it to both shared and My queries or whatever it was called. But if I leave Logs and go back in, I cannot find my query. I see a history for the queries I ran, but no definitions. 

My goal is to pin this to a health dashboard which I have created. I have used the Pin to Dashboard from within the logs. I don't see any data on the Dashboard tile. 

Could you tell me what is going on please?

Comment: @BryanSchmiedeler could you please attach a screenshot of your dashboard? I think you didn't specify the time range in the dashboard. In dashboard, the default `time range`  is 24hour, and also notice that the max `time range` is no more than 31days.

Comment: Ivan, sorry I forgot to go back and accept your answer. I have now done so. Thanks.